# Summernote editor validation for allow some html tags like <b>, <i>, <ul>, <li> but not special characters

Tags: html, jquery, summernote

I am using many patterns but not found any proper pattern for allow string with some HTML tags and without HTML tags.

This pattern allows HTML tags but not a simple string

```
<textarea id="description" class="summernote" maxlength="500" data-parsley-pattern="/<(p|span|ul|li|i|u) ?.*>(.*)<\/(p|span|ul|li|i|u)>/"></textarea>
```

allowed values should be : 1.  **Adfg gfg gdfsg gvdsfgdsr**

2. - **This is for test description**
   - **test for**
3. dasdasddsad

should not be allowed : >@>$#@$>
./34.3/2.2/34
34
34234
$#%#$$#

Please help me

Comment: Elaborate your question a bit, like examples for what is supposed to be allowed and what is not supposed to be.

Comment: I am using summernote  text editor  and i need to validate my text box allow only some HTML tags but not allow any special character like $@&%

Comment: please check by edited question

Comment: can you please update if it works for you?

Comment: it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you want to allow the whole tag ( with attributes and text with it, special chars are allowed in attributes but not in text area) you can use this.

**For all examples : Highlighted will be matched**

Aenean lacinia bibendum `<a href="/life">life</a>` sed consectetur. `<a href="/work">Work</a>` quis risus eget urna mollis ornare `<a href="/about">about</a>` leo. "

```
/<\s*([a-z]?)[^>]*>([a-zA-Z0-9_]*?)<\s*/\s*([a-z]?)>/g
```

If you only want to allow the tag name you can use this

It will match only tag names like =>  `<div>`, `<a>`, `<li>`

```
/<\s*([a-z]*?)[>]*\s*>/g
```

if you only want to accept one tag at a time: example =>`<div>`
use this:

```
/<\s*([a-z]*?)[>]*\s*>/
```

if you don't want to allow space at the start or end of the tags use (remove \s*)

```
/<([a-z]*?)[>]*>/
```

If you want to allow only some specific tags:

```
/<\s*((p|span|ul|li|i|u)1?)[>]*\s*>/
```

This will only allow specific tags and alphnumerics + _ in between , wont allow any attributes in tags:

Example: `<a>life klaskdjlaksjd lsdjk</a>`

```
/<\s*((p|span|ul|li|i|u|a)?)*>([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*?)<\s*/\s*((p|span|ul|li|i|u|a)1?)?>/
```